# Java displaytag form option

Tags: paging, jsp-tags, displaytag

In the documentation for displaytags there is a form option mentioned along with

Iam trying to use this option to post some data onto another page which will give me the next 10 results for a paginated view. But I get a js error saying

```
"Error: displaytagform is not defined
Source File: javascript:displaytagform('ss',[{f:'CityState',v:['']},{f:'Vendor',v:['Deepaks%20Cafe']},{f:'d-3996743-p',v:'2'}])
Line: 1"
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have found a solution by now, but just in case someone else might need the tip: you have to create a JavaScript function just like this: `displaytagform(arguments)`, where `arguments[0]` is the form name and `arguments[1]` is the array of object parameters with 'f' and 'v' as properties of each object. So you must set the parameters to the form one by one.